# How to convert a string in pandas dataframe into float or int

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have csv file, it looks like this:
[image]

The values of the first column 'Polygon' are strings. I would like to convert them into a sequence of nested lists, e.g. [[[1051381.5487, 7320839.9048], [1051368.1571, 7320819.7107],...]]].

To make it easier to understand I take only first 5 rows of the column:

```py
polygon = pd.DataFrame(germ.iloc[:5,0])
```

So it looks:

[image]

When I try to take the first row and to apply .astype(float)/.astype(int) it returns me this error:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '[[[1051381.5487 7320839.9048]\n  [1051368.1571 7320819.7107]\n  [1051343.0323 7320781.7935]\n  [1051309.9702 7320722.5248]\n  [1051296.0555 7320689.1256]\n  [1051278.0215 7320615.9572]\n  [1051263.9953 7320445.8771]\n  [1051260.4331 7320392.016 ]\n  [1051184.068  7320399.352 ]\n  [1051168.8172 7320476.7657]\n  [1051126.5157 7320604.76  ]\n  [1051098.3519 7320670.2061]\n  [1051051.9317 7320733.5289]\n  [1051014.9038 7320825.1753]\n  [1051007.6265 7320843.1868]\n  [1050998.81   7320865.8909]\n  [1050991.3741 7320885.0811]\n  [1050986.9211 7320934.5052]\n  [1050962.6534 7320983.3505]\n  [1050949.0725 7321018.2951]\n  [1050944.6197 7321061.3489]\n  [1050947.8481 7321075.4429]\n  [1050947.7366 7321104.4028]\n  [1050939.0538 7321143.0166]\n  [1050952.9687 7321178.7342]\n  [1050981.8005 7321221.7889]\n  [1050994.7134 7321231.4424]\n  [1051036.5695 7321236.8484]\n  [1051075.1974 7321267.1606]\n  [1051106.2556 7321282.0271]\n  [1051123.6215 7321240.3235]\n  [1051152.7872 7321191.0907]\n  [1051195.8679 7321126.6056]\n  [1051245.0709 7321050.7303]\n  [1051252.9745 7321038.3741]\n  [1051312.308  7320946.8614]\n  [1051362.9027 7320868.7095]\n  [1051381.5487 7320839.9048]]]'

Please help

Comment: Did you try using to_numeric use the following syntax ------ df['DataFrame Column'] = pd.to_numeric(df['DataFrame Column'], errors='coerce')

Comment: yes I did and got only NaN values

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the values are strings, that's why you couldn't convert them.

Perhaps try

```py
import ast
ast.literal_eval(insert your value/string here)
```

Check if string

```py
def perfectEval(anonstring):
    try:
        ev = ast.literal_eval(anonstring)
        return ev
    except ValueError:
        corrected = "\'" + anonstring + "\'"
        ev = ast.literal_eval(corrected)
        return ev
```

Comment: I can't use it, get ValueError: malformed node or string. Yes, the values are strings

Comment: hmm, perhaps try converting it into a string if it isnt?
Something like this (refer above)

Comment: if I take e.g.  `a =polygon.iloc[0,0]` and apply your function to it, i get the error:

  File "<unknown>", line 1
    [[[1051381.5487 7320839.9048]
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax